# Updating a point in a line chart when data grouping is in effect

Tags: highcharts

I need to update a specific point in the chart when new data arrives. I've written the following function:

```
function updatePoint(series, x, y) {
  for (i = 0; i < series.data.length - 1; i++) {
      var point = series.data[i];
      if (point.x === x) {
          point.update(y);
          return;
      }
  }
}
```

This works fine, unless the chart has more than turboThreshold points, in which case the series.data is gone, and I only have series.xData and series.yData to work with. I tried the following variant, but the chart does not actually update:

```
function updateTurboPoint(series, x, y) {
  for (i = 0; i < series.xData.length; i++) {
      if (series.xData[i] === x) {
          if (series.yData.length > i) {
              series.yData[i] = y;
              return;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Setting a breakpoint on the return, I verified that series.yData[i] has the new value, even though it did not appear on the chart. How can I get this to actually update the chart?

I am using HighStock 2.0.4.

**EDIT**: Created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swish014/2unh1cLa/

**EDIT**: Changed the title, as I (now) do not believe turbo mode has anything to do with it.

Comment: Do you have `dataGrouping` enabled or disabled?

Comment: Check if `series.points` array exists, and try to update that points. If won't resolve your issue, recreate issue on jsFiddle (with some static data) - we will check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two comments were key to figuring out my own problem.

It is related to dataGrouping (and not turbo mode as I first thought).

The series.points array does exist, and updating a point there does update the chart as desired.

In my question, I listed two separate functions to update points, but I believe I can use just one function:

```
function updatePoint(series, x, y) {
  for (i = 0; i < series.points.length - 1; i++) {
      var point = series.points[i];
      if (point.x === x) {
          point.update(y);
          return;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the [API docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series) lists the `data` array, but does not list the `points` array. Since `points` always seems to exist, I wonder why they don't just document that (or at least both).

Comment: Because `points` is for internal use. Using this as I suggested is rather workaround than a real solution. If you want better documentation, you need to check the source code.

Comment: So, am I to infer then that there is no supported way to update the chart when data grouping kicks in? The `points` workaround is fine for now, but sounds like it might break in a future release.

Comment: Yes, it can break. Problem with updating grouped points is that how to determine which points should change. Let's say you have grouped 24 hours into one point (day). Now you update that day point -> how should hour values change?

Comment: Fully working solution will be to [remove point](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.removePoint) and then add that point with new value. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xb8n3h0e/